JAXB OutOfMemoryError when marshalling large file
I'm getting OutOfMemoryError error when marshalling large file as follows:
public <T> String toString(JAXBElement<T> element) {
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    marshal(element, sw);
    return sw.toString();
}

public <T> void marshal(JAXBElement<T> element, final Writer writer, MarshallerProperty... msProps) {
    try {
        **createMarshaller(msProps).marshal(element, writer);**
    } catch (JAXBException ex) {
        throw new JaxbSystemException(
                "ConsumptionJaxbHelper failed to marshal " + element.getClass().getTypeName(), ex);
    }
}

private Marshaller createMarshaller(MarshallerProperty... msProps) {
    try {
        Marshaller m = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

        m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
        m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.FALSE);
        m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
        
        for(MarshallerProperty msProp : msProps) {
            m.setProperty(msProp.getPropertyName(), msProp.getPropertyValue());
        }
        return m;
    } catch (JAXBException ex) {
        throw new JaxbSystemException("ConsumptionJaxbHelper failed to create Marchaller.", ex);
    }
}

Stack dump, and error occour at createMarshaller(msProps).marshal(element, writer); on above code.
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: null
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.hugeCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:214) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.newCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:206) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:173) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:686) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:414) ~[?:?]
at java.io.StringWriter.write(StringWriter.java:99) ~[?:?]
at java.io.BufferedWriter.flushBuffer(BufferedWriter.java:120) ~[?:?]
at java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(BufferedWriter.java:256) ~[?:?]
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.cleanUp(MarshallerImpl.java:347) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.4.0-b180830.0438.jar:2.4.0-b180830.0438]
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:340) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.4.0-b180830.0438.jar:2.4.0-b180830.0438]
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:256) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.4.0-b180830.0438.jar:2.4.0-b180830.0438]
at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractMarshallerImpl.marshal(AbstractMarshallerImpl.java:101) ~[jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]

I have increased the memory but that didn't help.
EDIT 1:
Using Jdk 11/tomcat 9, before memory was set to 4096, change to 12288 and VM has 16GB. Crashing when around 6GB of memory in use, and plenty of free memory. I'm looking for solution to handle larger string.

Don't stream into memory when you can stream direct to file or other output channels (eg servlet response). Double check you aren't marshalling excessive network of related classes.

"I have increase the memory" What was the configuration before? What did you change? Are there any error log files? Which JDK version? Does the application crash? Read [ask] would be a good start to improve this question. Having said that, creating a huge string in memory is probably the cause of your issue.
